# Creating Attendance Sheet from acces control output

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need to find the first time in and last time for each employee from the output of access control. This has to be saved in another sheet. Sample data attached, can you help on this

[image: A more readable version of the table data posted]

Data Below:

```
Event Time  Time    User ID User Name   Department  Terminal ID Terminal Name
11/18/13 8:44   08:44:06    '0101   Mike        5   GFENTRANCE
11/18/13 13:42  13:42:38    '0101   Mike        6   GFEXIT
11/18/13 13:42  13:42:57    '0101   Mike        5   GFENTRANCE
11/18/13 13:43  13:43:31    '0101   Mike        6   GFEXIT
11/18/13 16:13  16:13:11    '0101   Mike        6   GFEXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want but in Sheet2 of the same workbook I used:

```
=Sheet1!B2
```

To get the first time and;

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B, COUNTA(Sheet1!B:B), 1)
```

To get the last time for that record. Make sure the cells are time formatted because the results wont look right unless they are.